# failed capistrano deploy with missing manifest.*json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

Capistrano 3.0 deploy failed on rails 3.2 because there is not manfest.*json with the following error.

However, there is manifest.yml which is expected for rails 3.2 while rails 4.0 expects manifest.json. any idea why this happening or how i can go about it.

```
 INFO [b38cf17e] Running /usr/bin/env cp /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102161642/public/assets/manifest*.json /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102161642/assets_manifest_backup.json on 208.68.39.56
DEBUG [b38cf17e] Command: cd /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102161642 && /usr/bin/env cp /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102161642/public/assets/manifest*.json /var/www/html/webapp/releases/20140102161642/assets_manifest_backup.json
cap aborted!
cp stdout: Nothing written
cp stderr: Nothing written
```

Thank you in advance..